# How can I retrieve an HTTPS URL on Mac OS X without warnings about an untrusted authority?

Tags: osx, url, gnutls

The following code should in principle return the contents of https://badssl.com

```
(with-current-buffer
    (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://badssl.com")
  (buffer-string))
```

But with my `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1112)) of 2015-08-24` on OS X 10.10.5, run with `-Q`, it instead shows me this message:

```
Certificate information
Issued by:          COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
Issued to:          Domain Control Validated
Hostname:           *.badssl.com
Public key:         RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256
Protocol:           TLS1.2, key: ECDHE-RSA, cipher: AES-128-GCM, mac: AEAD
Security level:     Medium
Valid:              From 2015-04-09 to 2016-07-07


The TLS connection to badssl.com:443 is insecure for the following
reasons:

the certificate was signed by an unknown and therefore untrusted authority
certificate could not be verified
```

and asks whether to accept the certificate - No/Session/Always. It then works if I accept the certificate.

I do not experience the same problem with, for example, wget. Wget correctly downloads (without asking the question) https://badssl.com and rejects https://self-signed.badssl.com.

Moreover, there appear to be *two* separate customization groups - gnutls and tls. I have previously compiled emacs with support for gnutls (`gnutls-available-p` returns `t`). Gnutls was installed with homebrew.

If I set `gnutls-verify-error` to `t`, I instead get the error

```
gnutls-negotiate: Certificate validation failed badssl.com, verification code 42
```

so presumably gnutls was not being used in the first example. On OS X none of the files mentioned in `gnutls-trustfiles` (in `/usr/ssl` and `/etc/ssl`) exist.

So how can I configure emacs to use the default trusted root certificates on OS X?

*Edit:* If I install `libressl` from homebrew, and add `/opt/brew/etc/libressl/cert.pem` to `gnutls-trustfiles`, the issue disappears when using `gnutls-verify-error` set to t.

*Edit 2:* In my testing it didn't seem like the value of `tls-certtool-program` was actually used, but it may be incorrect for OS X anyway: the default certtool on OS X is not the GnuTLS certtool required by tls.el, and with homebrew's gnutls I think it should be gnutls-certtool instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour with current Emacs trunk.  Yours is rather old, please build current trunk and try again.

Comment: @lunaryorn I get the same issue with the current trunk.

Comment: How did you build Emacs?  Particularly, what flags did you use?

Comment: @lunaryorn `../emacs/configure --with-ns CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/brew/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/brew/lib` (`../emacs` being a clone of `git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git`) then `make` and `make install`. The configure output says it uses `-lgnutls`.

Comment: @lunaryorn Do you get an error (as expected) connecting to expired.badssl.com or self-signed.badssl.com instead of badssl.com in the example?

Comment: @Kirill: If you've resolved the problem (as it looks like you have from your edit), please post an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Kirill Yes I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this issue it seems sufficient to:

- Set `gnutls-verify-error` to `t`, and
- Add an appropriate trusted root certificate file to `gnutls-trustfiles` - the default setting for that list does not include any existing files on OS X and it doesn't seem to default to using the system keychain.

This can be done, for example, by installing `libressl` from homebrew and adding the file `$(brew --prefix)/etc/libressl/cert.pem` - homebrew says this file is created from the system keychain. Setting the variable `gnutls-log-level` to a positive value shows that it does actually use that file.

*Note:* With these settings I get an extra unrelated message from gnutls saying

> gnutls.c: [audit] Note that the security level of the Diffie-Hellman key exchange has been lowered to 256 bits and this may allow decryption of the session data

This can be fixed by setting `gnutls-min-prime-bits` to a value higher than the emacs default (256) and higher than what gnutls considers insecure (768) such as 3072, see http://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Selecting-cryptographic-key-sizes.html as well as http://www.keylength.com/en/3/ - this sets the minimum group size for Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: Is there any plan to get Emacs to work correctly by default? This seems like an awful lot of work.

Answer (score 8):

Add `/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem` to `gnutls-trustfiles`:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> customize-variable
2. `Customize variable:` gnutls-trustfiles
3. Select the last `[INS]`
4. `Bundle filename:` /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem
5. Select `[ Apply and Save ]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem` seems to do the job.

Comment: Please clarify how/where to add it, and clarify what "it" is (do you mean a file or a file name?),