# Cannot access gnu.org from macOS

Tags: osx, package-repositories

I am using a MacBookPro with macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 using Chrome as a browser. I cannot access elpa.gnu.org or www.gnu.org. As a result my emacs installation does not work anymore.

Comment: Can you access those websites from your browser?

Comment: Might be related to this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18070/14114

Comment: This is now solved. I have added 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 to the list of DNS servers and now I can access gnu.org.